# MultiTouch on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, multi-touch, android-virtual-device

It's possible to test the multi-touch feature into the AVD?

I read this thread
[Android Multitouch - Possible to test in emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082707/android-multitouch-possible-to-test-in-emulator)

But it's for 2.0 and maybe this can be added since Jan/2010

Comment: How would you do it?  Two mouse pointers?  :)

Comment: I don't know, maybe a hotkey I press and the first point DOWNs somewhere and I move the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-touch is not supported in  the emulator.
There is an [open issue in the Android issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5977) for multi touch support in the emulator. It's not accepted by Google but you can star it.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thanks