# How to pass multi touch events to the device using adb?

Tags: android, adb, multi-touch

Is there any way to pass multi-touch events to the device using adb, using android action events? (Accessing the device remotely using the adb commands).

Comment: Is it now possible to test multi touch in recent emulator?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082707/android-multitouch-possible-to-test-in-emulator

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that multitouch is not supported in the emulator, sorry? It is usually best to test on a device anyway.