# How to pinch zoom on Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, pinchzoom

I have an application in which I need to implement image editing, which also includes pinch zooming. I am done with pinch zooming but I can test this only on device, not on emulator.

Is there any way for testing pinch zooming in android emulator, any shortcut key or any other way?

Comment: for that you must have touchscreen moniter. you cant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082707/android-multitouch-possible-to-test-in-emulator

Comment: ok means there is not any shortcut from keyboard for that

Comment: Basically a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082707/android-multitouch-possible-to-test-in-emulator

Comment: This is an old question and I think the best answer is currently cmd (⌘) pressed for Mac (i.e. answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40040692/2848676).

Comment: Ctrl+z is shortcut for grabbing magnifier and pressing it again release it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since ADT 17, it is possible to use a physical Android 4.0 device to send multitouch gestures to the emulator.[See Android's instructions here](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation).

**Multi-Touch**

The emulator supports multi-touch input, as an experimental feature in r17, using a tethered Android device running the SdkControllerMultitouch application. The application contains an activity that monitors touch inputs and sends them to the emulator. This requires an Android 4.0 or later system image.
The activity displays the content of the emulator screens to help with interactivity. It is recommended to enable "show touches" in the Developer section of the Settings on the emulator to see exactly where the touches are sent.

The SdkControllerSensor application source code is located in

> $SDK/tools/apps/SdkControllerMultitouch/

But this is still a workaround since we need a real device. My advice would be to test your app directly on a real device as it's more robust, and even more performant.

Comment: Dude people who ask this question don't have physical devices. If you already have a physical Android device, why would you still need the emulator for?

Comment: @Pacerier I have one physical device but I still need the emulator to test on multiple devices.

Comment: Android SDK emulator: Double click + CTRL is what worked for me. Rest of the answers didn't

Comment: I was able to get it to work on a Mac by holding down the Command key and then options for pinching were available with my mouse.

Answer (score 167):

**With a mouse:**

Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press and hold left mouse and while doing that move your mouse.

**With a trackpad:**

Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press and hold your trackpad and move with a finger to the LEFT and RIGHT (not up and down).

Comment: Is this for normal emulator or genymotion ?

Comment: @yowbro, How did you figure this out?

Comment: Double-clicking worked for me with the regular mouse and did not use trackpad. CTRL did nothing to change it.

Comment: As of Android Studio 2.1.2, it works. Hold CTRL + left-click to set the gesture center, then either drag away from center to zoom out, or move (not drag!) away from center, *then* drag towards the center to zoom in. For me, the cursor changed to a Holo-blue target icon at the center, with dashed lines indicating the emulated zoom pointers.

Comment: Another way to set the gesture center: Depress SHIFT, and hold it down as you press CTRL. Gesture will be centered on the mouse location at the time you pressed CTRL.

Comment: For this to work you also have to make sure that you've got "Settings -> General -> Send keyboard shortcuts to" set to "Emulator controls"

Answer (score 28):

I know it's late reply but this might save someones time.

**Double-click** and then hold down the second click and move the mouse **up to zoom out** or **down to zoom in**.

Hope this works!

Comment: This worked for me on Android x86 + Virtualbox.

Ctrl + double click & drag

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio Emulator.

Comment: Great! This one was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

On a Mac running the latest version of AndroidStudio and a vanilla Nexus 5 API 24 emulator all you have to do is keep ***cmd*** (**⌘**) pressed.

[image]

The drag points will appear. 
After that just left click and drag anywhere on the screen!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Android Emulator running API 25 (7.1). Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me on Linux in 2018.

Comment: Ctrl + Click works for me on windows android emulator.

Comment: FWIW, there currently seems to be a bug that causes this not to work if your emulator settings are set to "Emulator always on top".

Comment: how to turn it off back?

Comment: On a Mac the cmd (⌘) button only simulates pinch gestures on an Android emulator running as a standalone application.  It does not seem to work when I [Run the Android Emulator directly in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio).

Answer (score 12):

OK, I was experimenting a bit, and on the bluestacks android emulator, I've figured it out.

It is **Ctrl+Mouse wheel**.
Works for me, hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is old but this might still help someone.

On mac:

To  `zoom in` use `double click`
(on track pad)

To `zoom out` use Command + Shift + `click` (on track pad)

Comment: Works for me on Mac!

Answer (score 6):

There has been some progress in this field with android tools release 17 : you can use a device to control the emulator : http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html.

Otherwise, it looks like testing on real device is just better for this case (and in general its also much faster).

Answer (score 6):

For mac: Use the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key and then use your mouse or trackpad to pinch/zoom. This is working on the android studio emulator.

You can find all the shortcuts in the extended controls menu, by pressing the three dots on the menu and then navigating to "help".

Answer (score 5):

1. Click 3 points (like preferences on emulator)
2. Settings
3. set param "Send keyboard shortcuts to" from "Virtual device" to "Emulator controls"
   now gestures work perfect!

Comment: Thank you for this lifesaver. It was working by default because "Emulator controls" is supposed to be the default choice, but I suddenly lost it. I rebooted everything to no avail, then found this lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

**An Android Emulator doesn't support multi-touch you can't test it on emulators. Please use real-device for multitouch testing.**

*For recent developments in this regard read this - http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation*

Answer (score 1):

PinchZoom works on Multi-Touch.

If the device is supporting multi-touch then only your code will work else it wont work.

As the Android Emulators doesn't support multi-touch you can't test it on emulators.

Still new ADT has feature But I never tried [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation)

Answer (score 1):

1. CTRL + a click on left side of the view screen will zoom out.
2. Double click on a location will zoom in.
3. North and South -> Scroll wheel - up and down
4. West-> CTRL+Scroll up at left side of the screen
5. East-> CTRL+Scroll up at right side of the screen

Answer (score 1):

On macbook with Android studio Bumblebee, I have to hold control first which lets the drag pointer to appear on the screen. Then all I need to do is double tap, hold the second tap, and drag to zoom-in/out.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 1, 2016 for the Android Studio's emulator on Windows. The pinch key on the emulator is the Alt key. Hold down Alt and click and drag your mouse button.

The CTRL key might still work for you, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the screen position from which the pinch zooming will be made if you press SHIFT before pressing the CTRL-key and continue to keep both keys pressed while you click and move your mouse/pointing device. The same should work for MacOs with SHIFT and the OPTION-key.

Without SHIFT, all zooming is done using the screen center as the origin.

Answer (score -3):

You can not able to test pinch zoom in Emulator. Please use Real device to test pinch zoom effect.

I have not try with youwave. May be you can able to test pinch in that environment.
Not sur but just try with it.

Enjoy Coding....