# Android Pinch Zoom Not working in Emulator

Tags: android, view, pinchzoom, android-gesture

I am creating a simple application for android

> ScaleGestureDetectore

for Image Which uses the  **pinch zoom**

feature but it is not working on emulator **Android Build Version 2.2**

My Code for the Activity is As follows:

```
package com.example.androidgesturedemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView img;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private float scale = 1f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);

        return true;

    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            img.setImageMatrix(matrix);

            return true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: ckeck with real device not working with emulater

Comment: why it is not working with emulator it should work

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023554/not-able-to-pinch-zoom-on-emulator

Comment: So you mad an view that reacts to pinch zoom on an emulator? How do you expect to make a _multi-touch_ gesture on the emoulator using only _one_ mouse?

Comment: @Gumbo wondering if it's even possible with two mice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test Multitouch in emulator with the help of a real device. Check [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation) how to do that.

Comment: So folowint this instructoin you can use a _real_ android device to control an _emulator_ over usb? Why don't you use the phone directly for testing?

Comment: @Gumbo If you want to test your app in multiple screen sizes and multiple devices, you can create n number of emulators and test with a single real device instead of buying n real phones.

Comment: Well, didn't think about it that way :)

Comment: cntrl + pinch zoom in out then its possible

Comment: @DaxeshKhatri Pinching needs two fingers. Control+pinch? How? Can you pinch me using one finger?

Comment: why are you test in emulator . emulator not provide some facility as well. double tap then pich zoom also

Comment: Use the Control key to test multiple touches.