# Android emulator pinch to zoom anywhere on screen (mac OS)

Tags: android, android-emulator, multi-touch, pinchzoom

I have already looked at [How to pinch zoom on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023554/how-to-pinch-zoom-on-android-emulator) but haven't found specifically **how to pinch zoom on any part of the screen** via emulator.

I'm on mac OS so I know I can hold <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and two dots will apear and I can drag when holding left mouse button to simulate pinch-to-zoom gesture.

However this happens only from the center of the screen. For example iOS emulator allows to move this center anywhere. I would like something similar for Android emulator as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not using a Mac, but here's my solution on Ubuntu:

1. Move the mouse cursor to the place you want to center the pinch gesture.
2. Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

This should display the gesture indicator centered on the mouse cursor.

On Mac, there should be equivalent keys, but I don't use Macs so I don't know.

Comment: Hmm doesn't work for me (Ubuntu), it's still center in the middle of the sceen

Comment: @JonasVautherin Sorry to hear that. I just tried again on my Google Pixel (Android 11) emulator and it worked, I followed the steps I posted. The key is to press (and hold) Shift before CTRL.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Machine the Sequence is
`Shift` + `Command⌘` and drag

[image]